# Lua: Variables stored in array

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to iterate over many variables at once, which are stored in a long array. To initialise them, I'm using a loop which goes over each of them, setting every variable to 0. By default, e.g. using: `array[count] = 0` it will only change the value of the table's index. How do I set this variable from inside the table, as in getting the variable stored inside and changing it, not just the table's value at the given index?

Comment: I didn't understand what are you talking about.  Some examples?

Comment: There are no reference types in Lua like in, e.g. C++ `int &a = b`.  So once you copy something into the table it “forgets” where it came from and loses every connection to the original variable.

Comment: @HenriMenke Oh, well then is there an alternative way to iterate over variables?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I have a table like so: arr =  { var1, var2, var3 }, and I can't set them with arr[1] = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to store *fields* in a Lua table:

```
a = { current = 4, first = 2, last = 10 }
```

Then you can set

```
a.current = 6
```

and also traverse all fields:

```
for k,v in pairs(a) do
   print(k,v)
end
```

or clear them with

```
for k in pairs(a) do
   a[k]=0
end
```